# WCF Query Interceptors: Is this MSDN sample a security risk?

Tags: c#, security, entity-framework, wcf-security, odata

If you look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744837.aspx) MSDN documentation there is a sample with the following code:

```
// Define a change interceptor for the Products entity set.
[ChangeInterceptor("Products")]
public void OnChangeProducts(Product product, UpdateOperations operations)
{
    if (operations == UpdateOperations.Add ||
       operations == UpdateOperations.Change)
    {
        // Reject changes to discontinued products.
        if (product.Discontinued)  //<-- IS THIS BASED ON UNVERIFIED CLIENT DATA???
        {
            throw new DataServiceException(400,
                        "A discontinued product cannot be modified");
        }
    }
    else if (operations == UpdateOperations.Delete)
    {
        // Block the delete and instead set the Discontinued flag.
        throw new DataServiceException(400, 
            "Products cannot be deleted; instead set the Discontinued flag to 'true'"); 
    }
}
```

Look at the comment in all CAPS.  My question is: "Is that line dependent on client supplied data... and if so, what can we do to have a secure validation"?

Comment: Thanks for reporting a possible issue in the documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change interceptor should get the entity AFTER the modifications from the client were applied to it. So the behavior depends on the provider. If your provide implements this property as read-only (which usually means any updates to it are ignored), then there's no problem with the above check. I do agree the sample could be better in this regard though.
Also depending on your provider, if this property is not read-only, you need to ask the provider for the unchanged/previous value. The way to do that depends on the provider. So if it's EF, this is more of an EF question how to determine the original value of a modified property (The entity instance will be tracked on the current data source).

Comment: "after the modifications were applied to it"... does that mean a client HTTP post will round trip some (possibly) invalid data, it gets applied to (a) the EF or (b) the provider.  if case "b" then, will the SQL server get a "write" and then rollback the transaction?

Comment: If the provider is EF, then the implementation applies the changes to the server-side EF entities (instances of the EF generated classes, the Product class in the sample above), but those changes are not transmitted anywhere yet, as SaveChanges was not called on the underlying EF context.

Comment: If the provider is not-EF, then the actual behavior depends on the provider's implementation of the IUpdatable interface, but if it follows spec on this one, it should behave in a similar manner as the SaveChanges was not called yet and thus the changes should be just cached locally on the server and not applied to any persitant storage.